# How can I place right bar button items on top of each other in nav bar (Xcode)?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, uinavigationbar

Right now my nav bar looks looks like this:

[image]

I was wondering how I could stack the flashlight and airplane on top of each other, kind of like how snapchat does it, while both still being bar button items?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't stack 2 navigation bar icons through xcode. What you could do though is screenshot those two icons, use a photo editor to put them on top of each other, save it to your computer, then drag & drop it into assets.xcassets in your project. Then, you should be able to set your custom image from the storyboard.
If your two navigation bar buttons previously did separate things when clicked, it won't be able to do that anymore.